# SQL Check duplicated values in different fields

Tags: mysql, sql

Hello so I have a database and a table named `datalist` and it has some dummy data. Here's the screenshot of the table in `phpmyadmin`.

[image]

What I wanted to do is to output the duplicates in every field. As you can see there are 2 `1111` and 2 `2222` data, but they're both from different fields. How can I output something like:

```
Duplicates:
1111
2222
```

I'm sorry for my question, but I only know checking of duplicate data on the same field only. Hope someone can help me, thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT
  f,
  COUNT(*)   overall_occurrences,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN field = 1 THEN f END)   AS f1_occurrences,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN field = 2 THEN f END)   AS f2_occurrences,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN field = 3 THEN f END)   AS f3_occurrences,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN field = 4 THEN f END)   AS f4_occurrences
FROM
(

    SELECT 1 AS field, f1 AS f, datalist.* FROM datalist
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 2 AS field, f2 AS f, datalist.* FROM datalist
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 3 AS field, f3 AS f, datalist.* FROM datalist
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 4 AS field, f4 AS f, datalist.* FROM datalist
)
   pivotted
WHERE
   somefield = 0
GROUP BY
   f
HAVING
   COUNT(*) > 1
```

***EDIT***: Updated to additionally show where the duplicates occur.

***EDIT***; alternative for slightly less repeating of logic...

*(Possibly not necessary here, but example of method that can be useful in more complex scenarios.)*

```
SELECT
  f,
  COUNT(*)   overall_occurrences,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN field = 1 THEN f END)   AS f1_occurrences,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN field = 2 THEN f END)   AS f2_occurrences,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN field = 3 THEN f END)   AS f3_occurrences,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN field = 4 THEN f END)   AS f4_occurrences
FROM
(

    SELECT
        pivotter.field,
        CASE pivotter.field
            WHEN 1 THEN datalist.f1
            WHEN 2 THEN datalist.f2
            WHEN 3 THEN datalist.f3
            WHEN 4 THEN datalist.f4
        END   AS f,
        datalist.*
    FROM
        datalist
    CROSS JOIN
    (
        SELECT 1 AS field
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 2 AS field
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 3 AS field
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 4 AS field
    )
        AS pivotter
)
   pivotted
WHERE
   somefield = 0
GROUP BY
   f
HAVING
   COUNT(*) > 1
```

Comment: If I will add (AND somefield = 0), should I put it inside the parenthesis?

Comment: @FewFlyBy - Updated with how I'd do it, to avoid writing `somefield = 0` 4 times.  SQL Optimisers are clever enough that through "macro-like expansion" the WHERE clause on the Outer query gets passed through to the four individual Inner queries.

Comment: Will try it now sir. You sir is a genius

Comment: Should I specify the table of somefield? Because I am getting unknown column

Comment: I edited the inner four queries too.  You need to include `somefield` on each of the four inner queries, or as I have it currently, `datalist.*` to pick up All fields from the target table.